# Stake account info is not updated after epoch

Tags: web3.js, account-data

I delegate 30◎ the validator in 353 epoch. Stake account is  `2o5G3H5dCb2akeT1eU4Q9WUz7Ky8hco2QmoAQg2ki42Z`.

In 354 epoch I got rewards and my stake right now is 30.013167766◎.

But when I'm trying go get this info from blockchain, it's still 30◎.

My code is:

```
const filterParams: any = {
    filters: [{ memcmp: { bytes: userAddress, offset: 44 } }, { dataSize: 200 }],
};

const accounts = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(programId, filterParams);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to view lifetime stake account rewards?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6344/how-to-view-lifetime-stake-account-rewards)